# Has the nodejs crypto module been audited at all?

Tags: node.js, cryptography

I can't find an answer easily, just [long-winded](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/2833) [arguments](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/5798) about crypto in general. 
I'm asking because I came across the [tweetnacl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tweetnacl) module, and its [corresponding audit](https://cure53.de/tweetnacl.pdf).

Comment: directed the question to Indutny https://twitter.com/eljefedelrodeo/status/918635375840694273